# plot matplotlib aggregated data python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I need plot of aggregrated data

```py
import pandas as pd
basic_data= pd.read_csv('WHO-COVID-19-global-data _2.csv',parse_dates= ['Date_reported'] )
cum_daily_cases = basic_data.groupby('Date_reported')[['New_cases']].sum()

import pylab
x = cum_daily_cases['Date_reported']
y = cum_daily_cases['New_cases']
pylab.plot(x,y)
pylab.show()
```

`Error: 'Date_reported'`

```
Input: Date_reported, Country_code, Country, WHO_region, New_cases, Cumulative_cases, New_deaths, Cumulative_deaths 2020-01-03,AF,Afghanistan,EMRO,0,0,0,0
```

`Output: the total quantity of "New cases" showed on the plot per day.`

What should I do to run this plot? link to [dataset](https://covid19.who.int/table)

Comment: Don't use pylab. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`.

Answer (score 0):

The column names contain a leading space (can be easily seen by checking `basic_data.dtypes`). Fix that by adding the following line immediately after `basic_data` was read:

```
basic_data.columns = [s.strip() for s in basic_data.columns]
```

In addition, your x variable should be the index after `groupby-sum`, not a column `Date_reported`. Correction:

```
x = cum_daily_cases.index
```

The plot should show as expected.

[image: Imgur]

Comment: sorry, I made it earlier by: basic_data.rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip(), inplace=True)